# Can I use two hots in a 10-3 wg to power a 60am cir 115' away from main load center to power sub panel

Tags: electrical, subpanel

We ran 2 20 amp connections over the 10-3 and Now I am wondering if I can use the current two hots. to power a sub panel @ 50 or 60 amps 240.

Thanks,

D

Comment: Feel free to use whole words. There's no extra charge.

Answer (score 2):

20 amps must at minimum use 12 gauge wire or larger. So 10 gauge was okay, and might have been needed if the distance was far enough to prevent voltage drop.

30 amp breaker/circuit must use 10 gauge wire or larger

50 or 60 amp circuit must use 6 or 4 gauge wire.

10 gauge wire cannot be used on a circuit larger than 30 amps.

Comment: Well 10 awg can be used on larger inrush amperage devices like an AC compressor or motors but other than that I agree.

Comment: 50 or 60 Amps aluminum (even larger) wins quickly unless you have money to waste.